# Do I need support library v4 for google play services (ads)

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I want to use the ads system by google play services (Admob). I know I need to bundle the game services library. But do I need to bundle the support libraryV4 if I am targeting Appi 8 and above?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It used to be the case that the support library wasn't necessary, but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661200/android-is-support-library-v4-needed-for-google-play-services) the situation has changed with the release of Play Services 6.5.**

> As of Google Play Services 6.5, the play-services-base library (a
>   dependency for all Google Play Services) depends on the latest support
>   library.

---

**(Historical)**
Mobile Ads is part of [Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/ads.html), not the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html). If you just need Ads, then the Support Library is not necessary. Howerver, other features of Google Play Services, such as Maps, do need it.

You nevertheless do need to include the Support Library if you are using Fragments, ViewPager, or any of the other [features](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) it provides.