# android Is support library v4 needed for google play services?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, android-support-library

I know it has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717006/do-i-need-support-library-v4-for-google-play-services-ads) but this is what android studio is complaining about:

[image]

I am sure I am not referencing the support library anywhere in the gradle builds, but android studio complains that it is needed for google play services.

**EDIT:**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':comgizmogadgetsappzproductivity')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
}
```

comgizmogadgetsappzproductivity has no dependency.

**EDIT 2:**

The thing is that I had the support library as a dependency earlier, but I removed it since I didn't need it anymore. From the build error I can see it says that "configuration:app:_debugCompile" needs it. Maybe I need to manually remove the support library from _debugCompile configuration? Is "_debugCompile" a file? I tried searching for it with find and grep in the project folder but didn't find anything.

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment bc I want to leave room for somebody to answer with more detail, but apparently it is needed.

Comment: Weird... I just rechecked and it worked (well, compiled) :) fine without adding the support library. Is that the _only_ dependency in your project?

Comment: no, I have more but none need the support library. but as you can see in the screen shot it says "required by: app name:unspecified (what does that mean?) > play-services-ads"

Comment: Make sure you have downloaded the Support Library repository and Google Play Services repository through the SDK manager. It looks like the support repository was not installed.

Comment: @Maria Could you list your other dependencies?

Comment: @matiash I have listed the dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `gradlew :main:dependencies` (where `main` is your module name) should show you something like:

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.5.87
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0 -> 21.0.3
|              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3
```

As of Google Play Services 6.5, the `play-services-base` library (a dependency for all Google Play Services) depends on the latest support library.

Ensure that your Support Library is available via the SDK manager: you'd want to make sure `Android Support Library` and `Android Support Repository` are both installed and up to date